# Is there a widget(s) that can be used to custom-resize columns in a DataTable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running into a scenario where I want to be able to resize column widths in a DataTable widget by either clicking and dragging between the columns, **or** explicitly setting the widths of the columns / cells. Does anyone know if there is some widget or combination of widgets that I could use to accomplish this?

I'm looking to be able to create something like a draggable slider, to make it so I'd be able to go from something like this (either by click/dragging the red line on the right, or setting a value):
[image]

To something like this:
[image]

(The red lines are mostly for illustration purposes).
Is this possible without relying on an external package? I'd like to keep the look and functionality of the DataTable.

I have tried using ConstrainedBox on the Data Cells, like in the following example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Age',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Role',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: <DataRow>[
        const DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(
              ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 500),
              child: const Text('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz')
              )
            ),
            const DataCell(Text('43')),
            const DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            const DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(
              ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 500),
              child: const Text('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz')
              )
            ),
            const DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this link](https://fluttergems.dev/table/). There are a lot pre-build DataTable packages. You can choose which you like.